# How to solve the recurrence $T(n)=T(n-1)+\frac{n}{n-1}$?

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

> Solve the recurrence $T(n)=T(n-1)+\frac{n}{n-1}$.

I thought to try solving it by iteration method:
$$
T(n)=\frac{n}{n-1}+\frac{n-1}{n-2}+\frac{n-2}{n-3}+...+\frac{3}{2}+\frac{2}{1}=\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{i}{i-1}
$$
 I know that $\sum^n_i i=0.5n(n+1)$ but I don't know how to develop the series from here.

Comment: The recurrence makes no sense when $n=1$.

Comment: I guess you made a mistake on your expansion on the second fraction. the numerator should be $n-1$.

Comment: @Zubzub thanks, corrected it.

Comment: What's the start of the recurrence? You need $T(1)$, for example, before you can calculate anything else...

Comment: @5xum I guess it's $T(2)$ because for $T(1)$ it's undefined.

Comment: @Yos You can have $T(1)$ given, that way $T(2)=T(1)+\frac{2}{1}$ is not at all undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, at first let $T(1)=a\in\mathbb{R}$ be the first term of the sequence $T(n)$. Then, let us try to find some of the next terms of the sequence:
$$T(2)=T(1)+\frac{2}{2-1}=a+2$$
$$T(3)=T(2)+\frac{3}{3-1}=a+2+\frac{3}{2}=a+\frac{7}{2}(=a+3.5)$$
$$T(4)=T(3)+\frac{4}{4-1}=a+\frac{7}{2}+\frac{4}{3}=a+\frac{29}{6}(=a+4.8\overline{3})$$
And, in general:
$$T(n)=a+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{k}{k-1}$$
Now, we have:
$$\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{k}{k-1}=\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{k-1+1}{k-1}=\sum_{k=2}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{k-1}\right)=n-1+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k-1}$$
So, we have to calculate the sum:
$$\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}=H_{n-1}$$
Where $H_n$ is the $n$-th harmonic number.
So, we finally have:
$$T(n)=a+n-1+H_{n-1}$$

Comment: Is this an identity: $$\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}$$?

Comment: Well, it is actually a change of variable. If we set i=k-1 to the first sum we get the second sum. But, as a habbit, for such changes I am used to omit that step.

Comment: If you're making change of variable that $i=k-1$ then why you still have variable $k$ on the right hand side of the equality?

Comment: Then, one can set again $i=k$, so as to come back to $k$. It's a matter of taste. I don't want to use so many letters for indices etc and when I can avoid it, I dos so. ;)

Answer (score 3):

We have,

$$T(k)-T(k-1)=1+\frac{1}{k-1}$$

Summing both sides from $k=2$ to $n$ gives,

$$T(n)-T(1)=n-1+\sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k-1}$$

As the left hand side telescopes. Hence for $n \geq 2$,

$$T(n)=T(1)+(n-1)+H_{n-1}$$

Where $H_{n-1}$ represents the ${n-1}$th harmonic number.